# google Map in fragment DexIndexOverflowException error

Tags: android, dictionary, fragment

Hey guys i was trying to use google map in a fragment and i saw few tutorials and they all were using fragment activity not fragment.So i tried using the same code in fragment.but i am getting this error 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

below is my code of the fragment

```
  public class MapsActivity extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
MapView mapView;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
```

.............some fixed code in fragment (havent changed anything)

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
    mapView = (MapView)view.findViewById(R.id.MapView);

    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.onResume();
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);
  //  SupportMapFragment mapFragment = 
  (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager()
 //           .findFragmentById(R.id.MapView);
 //   mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
}

..................(some code i havent touched this part)


LatLng myPosition;
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;
    mFusedLocationClient = 
  LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext());

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), 
   android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && Activi 
   tyCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), 
 android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != 
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling

        return;
    }
    Task task= mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener((Executor) this, new 
  OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    // Got last known location. In some rare situations this 
  can be null.
                //    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"code run 
   here",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (location != null) {
                        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        String a,b;
                        a= String.valueOf(latitude);
                        b= String.valueOf(longitude);

                        Log.d(a,b);
                  //      
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),a+b,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        googleMap.addMarker(new 
  MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("Start"));

  mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));
                    }
                }
            });
}


public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

i have tried doing this but still the same results

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
  container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, 
 false);


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
  }


  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {




    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mapView = (MapView)view.findViewById(R.id.Map);
    if(mapView != null){
        mapView.onCreate(null);
        mapView.onResume();
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
       }
   }
```

laayout file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.jimmy.workmen.DashboardFragment.MapsActivity">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/Map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that i was using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

instead of using location alone it imports whole api 
so i replaced it by code below and it was working fine

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'
```